# What is the UML diagram representing for the structure of code?

Tags: uml

My source code is designed in a MVC structure as follow:

```
project
   |
   |-- Model
   |     |- data1, data2, data3, ...
   |
   |-- View
   |     |- view1, view2, view3, ...
   |
   |-- Controller
   |     |- controller1, controller2, ...
   |
   |-- Service
   |     |- webservice, socketservice, ...
   |
   |-- Utils
   |     |- customUI, commonLib, XMLHandler, ...
   |
   |-- Resources
   |     |- fonts, images, ...
   |
   |-- Deployment
   |     |- MSI setup, dependencies, ...
   |
```

Is there any UML diagram type to represent the above structure? Thanks.

Comment: UML type means UML diagram ?

Comment: I think, it can represent with site map.

Comment: site map is for web ? Any tool for mac to draw the site map diagram?

Comment: I am not confirm but i think, but i just giving you idea that i can build using site map. you can draw site map using visio, smartdraw etc.

Comment: can try this http://creately.com/diagram-type/site-map

Comment: I think your answer deserves as an answer. Thanks @RamPrasadG

Comment: @chipbk10  I posted this as an answer. can you pls accept as owner and vote up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site-map diagrams can serve this kind of requirements. there are several tools available one of the online tool you can consider is 
[site-map](http://creately.com/diagram-type/site-map)

---

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want to show the files, you can use a simple package diagram with objects inside that represent the single files:

[image]