# Can UML be used to represent document hierarchy?

Tags: uml

I am modeling a software development process in UML and would like to include a diagram which shows the hierarchy of system and software process documentation.  The results of a quick search indicate that there isn't a recognized standard for this.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624697/what-is-the-uml-diagram-representing-for-the-structure-of-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to model this in UML. If you are just modeling the documentation, each type of document would be a class on a class diagram. You can nest those classes in packages, show composition relations, or arrange the classes in a taxonomy using generalization. You could also use interacting state machine models, where each role in the process runs a state machine and each document runs a state machine.

There is a related, recognized standard for modeling system and software processes. Have you looked at the [Software & Systems Process Engineering 
Metamodel™ specification (SPEM™)](http://www.omg.org/spec/SPEM/2.0/)? That standard has a UML profile that may provide you with a good starting point.